# Is it possible to retrieve the string within the lambda expression?

Tags: kotlin, kotlintest

Writing tests using *String Spec*:

```
class stl : StringSpec() {

    init {

        "triangle.stl" {
             ...
        }
    }
}
```

Is it possible to retrieve `"triangle.stl"` within the lambda expression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't look like `StringSpec` exposes this information but you can extend `StringSpec` to do so. e.g.:

```
class Spec : StringSpec() {
    init {
        "triangle.stl" { testCase ->
            println(testCase.name)
        }
    }

    operator fun String.invoke(test: (TestCase) -> Unit): TestCase {
        var tc: TestCase? = null
        tc = invoke(fun() { test(tc!!) })
        return tc
    }
}
```

Or to avoid function conflicts with the exsting `String.invoke` you could extend it with your own syntax. e.g.:

```
class Spec : StringSpec() {
    init {
        "triangle.stl" testCase {
            println(name)
        }
    }

    infix fun String.testCase(test: TestCase.() -> Unit): TestCase {
        var tc: TestCase? = null
        tc = invoke { test(tc!!) }
        return tc
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You would have to store a reference to the string yourself. Something like

```
class stl : StringSpec() {
    init {
        val spek = "triangle.stl"
        spek {
             // use spek in here
        }
    }
}
```